# Increment through array with onclick- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a carousel of titles and images. When an image is clicked on, the question/title changes. I'm having trouble writing the function/code that will allow me to increment through the questionList array onclick.

```
var mycarousel_questionList= [
{qID: 1, title: "Question 1"},
{qID: 2, title: "Question 2"},
{qID: 3, title: "Question 3"},
];
```

^^that is my array

```
function mycarousel_questionListInc(){
   pages=mycarousel_questionList.length;
   var pageNo=0;
   document.onclick=pageNo++;
   mycarousel_questionList[pageNo].title;
}
```

^^that what I have so far.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any HTML to go with that?

Comment: I'm new to this, so I'm not exactly sure. I don't think so.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's code you're not showing here; judging by what you have shown, @Bergi's answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the function you already have as an [event listener](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html):

```
var pageNo=0;
function mycarousel_questionListInc(){
    pages=mycarousel_questionList.length;
    pageNo++;
    mycarousel_questionList[pageNo].title;
}
document.onclick = mycarousel_questionListInc;
```

Comment: It didn't work. The question/title comes up as Question1Question1 after 2 clicks, and so on.

Comment: It does. But there is no code that lets any title "come up", please show us your full code (and html page).